# org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal Crash When Using Gradle above 4.4

Tags: android, gradle

I created a new Android application project on MacOS and I faced this error when I tried to change `GradleWrapper` in Android Studio.

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
>   to
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
>   (4.4,4.5,4.6) Gradle build will toast this error

Does anybody know how can I fixed this issue?

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
       at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:84)
       at org.gradle.internal.classloader.DefaultClassLoaderFactory.createIsolatedClassLoader(DefaultClassLoaderFactory.java:61)
       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
       at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
       at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
       at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance an application has added `jar` libraries into your Mac's `/Library/Java/Extensions` directory.

Try removing or moving `xercesImpl.jar` to a temporary location. This has solved the problem on my Mac.